# How do I create a proper non-numeric list in COBOL?

Tags: list, concatenation, cobol

I'm trying to write a to-do list program in COBOL but I can't seem to make the list variable work. It keeps telling me that the ITEM variables are not numeric (which makes sense, they're not). So how do I create a list with non-numeric elements? Here is what my program contains so far (at least the relevant parts):

```
  "DATA DIVISION.

   FILE SECTION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 MORNING  PIC A(50).
   01 ITEM1    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM2    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM3    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM4    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM5    PIC A(20).
   01 AFTERNOON PIC A(50).
   01 ITEM6    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM7    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM8    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM9    PIC A(20).
   01 ITEM10   PIC A(20).
   01 THELIST  PIC A(50).
   01 ANSWER   PIC A(10).

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       0100-MAIN-PROCEDURE.
            DISPLAY "Hello, what needs doing today?".
            DISPLAY "You can have up to 10 items on your list.".
            DISPLAY "Let's start with the 1st 5 things you want to".
            DISPLAY "do in the morning".
       0200-MORNING.
            DISPLAY "what would you like to do first?".
            ACCEPT ITEM1.
            DISPLAY "And then?".
            ACCEPT ITEM2.
            DISPLAY "Next?".
            ACCEPT ITEM3.
            DISPLAY "And fourth?".
            ACCEPT ITEM4.
            DISPLAY "Now what's the last thing you'd like to do".
            DISPLAY "this morning?".
            ACCEPT ITEM5.
       0300-AFTERNOON.
            DISPLAY "Now for the afternoon.".
            DISPLAY "What do you want to do first?".
            ACCEPT ITEM6.
            DISPLAY "Alright, and then?".
            ACCEPT ITEM7.
            DISPLAY "Next?".
            ACCEPT ITEM8.
            DISPLAY "And what're the last 2 things you want to do?".
            ACCEPT ITEM9.
            ACCEPT ITEM10.

       0400-CHECKING-THINGS-OFF.
           COMPUTE THELIST = ITEM1 + ITEM2 + ITEM3 + ITEM4 + ITEM5 + ITEM6
           + ITEM7 + ITEM8 + ITEM9 + ITEM10.
           DISPLAY "Here's your list for the day:".
           DISPLAY THELIST.

       0500-CHECKING-THINGS-OFF-PART2.
           DISPLAY "Alright, let's start checking things off.".
       0600-ITEM1.
           DISPLAY "Have you completed ", ITEM1 "?".
           IF ANSWER = "yes" THEN 
               DISPLAY "Checked-off"
  *            COMPUTE THELIST1 = THELIST - ITEM1
               DELETE ITEM1
               DISPLAY THELIST1
           ELSE 
               GO TO 0600-ITEM1
           END-IF.
       0700-ITEM2.
           DISPLAY "Have you completed ", ITEM2 "?".
           IF ANSWER = "yes" THEN
               DISPLAY "Checked-off"
  *            COMPUTE THELIST2 = THELIST - (ITEM1 + ITEM2)
               DELETE ITEM2
           ELSE
               GO TO 0700-ITEM2
           END-IF."
```

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation is typically done with the STRING statement.

```
String
  ITEM1 Delimited Space
  ITEM2 Delimited Space
  ITEM3 Delimited Space
  ITEM4 Delimited Space
  ITEM5 Delimited Space
  ITEM6 Delimited Space
  ITEM7 Delimited Space
  ITEM8 Delimited Space
  ITEM9 Delimited Space
  ITEM10 Delimited Space
Into THELIST
Overflow Display 'Oops!'
End-String
```

Normally we see these items defined as `PIC X` instead of `PIC A`, as `A` only allows alphabetic characters [A-Za-z].  Also, I recommend using the `Value` clause on your Working-Storage items to ensure they are initialized to a known quantity, `Spaces` for example.

Rather than working with a concatenated list, I'd recommend you use an array, what COBOL calls a "table" by way of the `Occurs` clause.  Code a data structure that includes the item in your list and another item to indicate is has been "checked off."

```
01  TO-DO.
    05  TO-DO-LIST OCCURS 10 INDEXED TO-DO-INDX.
        10  TO-DO-ITEM    PIC X(20).
        10  TO-DO-DONE-SW PIC X.
            88  TO-DO-DONE           Value 'X'.
```

Then start off with `Move Spaces To TO-DO`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try this out as soon as I'm done work today